# Other documents features than tf-idf for clustering?

Tags: machine-learning, clustering, information-retrieval, natural-language

What are other feature representations for documents that are used for clustering textual documents? The only representation I'm aware of is tf-idf. Are there other ones?

Answer (score 1):

Technically, **TF/IDF is not a feature extraction scheme**.

The feature representation is "the words in the document". The TF/IDF part is the weighting of the individual features for similarity computation.

There are other representations, including bag of words, **n-grams** (really look this one up) and in a wider sense: minhash.

Answer (score 0):

For starters, tfidf is a family of term weighting functions. There are quite a few variants of it (e.g. pivoted tdidf), each of which has different properties. You could also use BM25 weights. BM25 has the advantage (?) that BM25 can/must be tuned using two parameters.